# Pymongo Query gets extremely slow

Tags: pymongo

I have a MongoDB base with a table with some 12M records and an index on Data.Report.FIELD field. I am trying to fetch all of its values. If I do it in one large cursor, it just dies on the way, so I split it in slices of 100K docs.

```
    for i in range (10):
        for a in data.find({'Data.Report.FIELD': {"$gt": (i*100000), "$lt": (i+1)*100000+1}},{'Data.Report.FIELD':1}):
            if ('FIELD' in a['Data']['Report'][0].keys()):
                _ids.append([a['_id'], a['Data']['Report'][0]['FIELD']])
                _FIELDs.append(a['Data']['Report'][0]['FIELD'])
                good+=1
            else:
                bad+=1
        print ('Done with ', i, ' hundred thousand. Time: ', time.time()-start, 'seconds.')
```

And what I get is something like:

```
Done with  0  hundred thousand. Time:  116.90340232849121 seconds.
Done with  1  hundred thousand. Time:  182.20432806015015 seconds.
Done with  2  hundred thousand. Time:  2561.886509180069 seconds. 
Done with  3  hundred thousand. Time:  4840.841073274612 seconds.
```

What could be the reason for it geting so crazily slow after 200K documents? Is there anything I could change? Could it be a server issue?

UPD:
Indexes:

```
{'_id_': {'v': 2, 'key': [('_id', 1)], 'ns': 'admin.ECR0618'},
 'FIELD': {'v': 2, 'key': [('Data.Report.FIELD', 1)], 'ns': 'admin.ECR0618',
  'background': False}}
```

Basic stats:

```
'ns': 'admin.ECR0618',
 'size': 176633446637.0,
 'count': 11782003,
 'avgObjSize': 14991,
 'storageSize': 59065884672.0,
 'capped': False,
```

Comment: Please post table schema, indexes, and statistics.

Comment: I have updated with the indexes and basic stats information.

I can't post the Schema, but it has tons of fields. But the point is, I'm trying to get only one field with my request.